# Android AutoCompleteTextView update

Tags: android, autosuggest, autocompletetextview

I have an activity which has two inputs : one for city and the other for location. I am storing the city and location information in sqlite table whenever the user request a search operation.

Now, i want whenever the user inputs the city(which is a autosuggest), the autosuggest options in location should automatically update. The input widget for location and city are both AutoCompleteTextView.

How can this be done?

Rgds,
Sapan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to provide a CursorAdapter to the AutoCompleteTextView, e.g. a SimpleCursorAdapter (though the SimpleCursorAdapter was buggy when i tried it).

```
Cursor cursor = getCityCursor();
int ids = int[]{R.id.autocomplete_list_item};

SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
  R.layout.list_item, cursor, new String[]{DB.COL_CITIES});

AutoCompleteTextView actvCities = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.cities);
actvCitites.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

the `getCityCursor();` method should provide a cursor obtained by a `SQLiteDatabase.query()`.

update: the "buggy" SimpleCursorAdapter i mentioned earlier isn't. just provide a `CursorToStringConverter`. [dan breslau](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/) wrote a pretty nice [article about AutoCompleteTextView and the SimpleCursorAdapter here](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-simpler-autocompletetextview-with-simplecursoradapter/).